# Button taking the height of background drawable android

Tags: android, drawable

I have a scrollview where I am adding a custom view programmatically.

The custom view is a `class A` which extends `LinearLayout`.
In the `class A`, I am using a `LinearLayout` as a view group and programmatically adding seven buttons in it and then setting a background drawable image to these seven buttons.

I have set fixed width for these buttons but still the button is taking larger height or might be the height of the drawable.

If I remove the background drawable image the height of buttons is fixed as provided.

In my main xml:

```
(ScrollView)
      (custom class A)
(/ScrollView)
```

in my custom view xml:

```
(RelativeLayout xmlns: ......)
(LinearLayout)
/------- In this I am adding buttons programmatically ---/**
(/LinearLayout)
(/RelativeLayout)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please share you java code and Xml file

Comment: is the size of the drawable the same as the fixed size you are setting?

Comment: does background drawable does not take the size of button?
Should I try Imageview as alternative by setting src and scale:fitxy..

Comment: Imageview works. The problem was the size of drawable. @Vemon Thanks.